# How to change the text of link

Tags: javascript, jquery

what i need

- i need to change text of link on click of that link.

html code

```
<a href="#" onclick="peopleattending('.$data[$k]['id'].','.$_COOKIE['user'].', this);" class="btn btn-primary btn-listing attend" id="attend" >Attend</a>
```

js code

```
    function peopleattending(evt_id,user,click)
    {

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"{{login_url_http}}/ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/"+evt_id + "/" + user+ "?visitor_flag=1&source=get-direction-oneclick", 
            success: function(data)
            {

                 $('click').text("Attending");
                 $( ".col-md-4" ).removeClass("mobilelisting" );
            }
        });

    }
```

debug

- on console.log click : url .
- i have also tried $(this).find("#attend").text("Attending"); not working.

working

```
     $("#attend").text("Attending");
```

- but my requirment i change text particular text of link text .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(click).text("Attending");
```

When you quote the `click` it becomes string. Instead you should pass the object directly. Without `quotes`